# Add number to incrementing list on button click in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Ok so in my code I'm supposed to enter a number between 4 and 15. Then I click a button to add it, Once that happens the number will be added to the total number of ages and to one of the leagues I have created (it should be incremented by 1, for example, if I enter a 12 it will be 1 if I enter 12 again the total will say 2). When I try and run the code it does nothing.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Soccer Manager</title>
<script>
function addAge()
{
// gets the input age
var age = Number(document.getElementById("age").value);

// clears the input field
document.getElementById("age").value = "";

// checks if age is between 4 and 15
if(age >= 4 && age <= 15){
// table cell to display total number of children
var total = document.getElementById("total");

// table cell to display total number of junior
var junior = document.getElementById("junior");

// table cell to display total number of intermediate
var intermediate = document.getElementById("intermediate");

// table cell to display total number of senior
var senior = document.getElementById("senior");

// increase total number of children by 1
total.innerHTML = Number(total.innerHTML) + 1;

// if its a junior age
if(age<=7)

// increase total number of junior by 1
junior.innerHTML = Number(junior.innerHTML) + 1;


// if its a intermediate age
else if(age<=11)

// increase total number of intermediate by 1
intermediate.innerHTML = Number(intermediate.innerHTML) + 1;


// else it will be a senior age
else

// increase total number of senior by 1
senior.innerHTML = Number(senior.innerHTML) + 1;

}

// if age is not between 4 and 15 alert an error
else{
window.alert("Age should be between 4 and 15");
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<center>
<h1>
Soccer Manager
</h1>
<div>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Total Children</th>
<td id="total">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Junior</th>
<td id="junior">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Intermediate</th>
<td id="intermediate">0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Senior</th>
<td id="senior">0</td>
</tr>
</table>


<input type="number" placeholder="Age"  id="age">

<button onClick="addAge()">Add</button>
</div>
</center>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Seeing `}` but no opening `{` on first glance. You can rid yourself of such syntax errors by *always* using `{}` on your if blocks and other structures. You can also open browser dev tools to see where syntax errors happen. I noticed yours from simply running your code here in SO `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'`

Comment: @mardubbles so I put it around each var like this? {var total = document.getElementById("total");} and around the if statement?

Comment: On the blocks, so `if (condition) { ... code follows }` consistently.

Comment: this? if(age >= 4 && age <= 15){
var total = document.getElementById("total");}
var junior = document.getElementById("junior");
var intermediate = document.getElementById("intermediate");
var senior = document.getElementById("senior");

{total.innerHTML = Number(total.innerhtml) +1;}
if(age<=7){

// increase total number of junior by 1
junior.innerHTML = Number(junior.innerHTML) + 1;}

else if(age<=11){
intermediate.innerHTML = Number(intermediate.innerHTML) + 1;}
else{
senior.innerHTML = Number(senior.innerHTML) + 1;}
else{
window.alert("Age should be between 4 and 15");}
}

Comment: It's a syntax error so just need to make sure your indentation is right (not needed, it's not Python code, but indentation helps to debug this error). Then simply from top, count `{` and see if matches up with a needed `}`.

Comment: @mardubbles it may not be needed for the computer but is definitely needed for the humans reading and writing the code, including the OP 

Comment: @virgo17 "it does nothing" - did you look into your developer console and notice the syntax error "unexpected token '}'"?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to add curly braces (`}`) in your statements.

---

To fix it, you need to add curly braces in the following locations.

```js
if (age >= 4 && age <= 15) {
  // Code...
} // Add me!

if (age <= 7) { // Add here!
  // Code...
} // Add here!

else if (age <= 11) { // Add here!
  // Code...
} // Add here!
```

---

Remember to add curly braces to make your JavaScript code work correctly!